# Failed with error: fatal unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/xyz/xyz.git/': The requested URL returned error: 502

Tags: git, android-studio, gitlab

I am trying to push my changes on Gitlab server using Android Studio but always I am getting an issue:

[image]

Comment: Are you using a proxy server? That 502 could be coming from your own proxy server, or it could be coming from gitlab itself if they are having some sort of service disruption.

Comment: @programmerq I am not using any proxy server. It seems that Gitlab server was down.